# How to remove the collection attribute in asp.net core MVC xml formatter

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core-webapi, owin

In .NET 5 I setup a webserver with OWIN

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
    }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
}
```

I have a Model PresEvents with a collection Events

```
public class PersEvents
{
    public List<Event> Events { get; } = new List<Event>();
}

public class Event
{
    public string Sn { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Loiname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

I have a controller returns this PersEvents instance

```
[HttpGet]
public PersEvents GetEventsData()
{
    PersEvents events = new PersEvents();
    events.Events.Add(new Event { Sn = "123", Loiname = "Ohio" });
    events.Events.Add(new Event { Sn = "456", Loiname = "Ohio" });
    return events;
}
```

When I call GetEventsData I can get the XML formatted data like below

```
<PersEvents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Events>
        <Event>
            <Sn>123</Sn>
            <Loiname>Ohio</Loiname>
        </Event>
        <Event>
            <Sn>456</Sn>
            <Loiname>Ohio</Loiname>
        </Event>
    </Events>
</PersEvents>
```

the question is I don't want the Events attribute, I just want all Event segments after PresEvents, How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make `PerseEvents` a collection type, then map all the inherited members to `this.Events`.

```
public class PersEvents : ICollection<Event>
{
    public List<Event> Events { get; } = new List<Event>();
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => this.Events.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, when I mapped all inherited members to this.Events, the response simply returns a JSON formatted data

Answer (score 0):

Finally I noticed add an attribute to the Events property can remove the container attribute.

```
[XmlElement("Event")]
public List<Event> Events { get; set; } = new List<Event>();
```